# accelerated C++ to find longest of palindrome

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdlist

I am practising  Koeing accelerated C++ , and want to verify my answer. Since there are no solutions available on net , I thought to post it here and ask experts view about my solution. I am not sure if people will like me to post it here. if not , please let me know and i will not do it in future. Also to mention, its not homework , its purely my desire to take my C++ skills to next level.

Question: **Write a program to find all the palindromes in a dictionary. Next, find the longest palindrome.**

**What I have done so far** -> I have defined function to test palindrome , also stored all words in a list. I have posted my code below.

**Where I am stuck:**  I need advice , whether my choice of using list data structure over vector is good or not? Secondly, I am stuck how to display longest word. I can display longest length  but not longest word.

my attempt below

```
    bool palindromeTest( const std::string& input )
{
   typedef std::string::size_type strSize;
    strSize i = 0;
    strSize j = input.size() - 1  ;
    while( i < input.size() )
    {
        if ( input[i] != input[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return true;
}



int main()
{

    // stores all words in a list or vector
    std::list< string> listDict;
    std::string readWord;
    std::ifstream readFile( "/Users/apple/palidndrome-ch5-10/dict.txt" );
    if( ! readFile )
    {
        std::cout <<" failed to open file" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while( readFile >> readWord )
    {
        listDict.push_back( readWord );
    }

     std::string::size_type maxLen = 0 ;
     std::string longestWord = " "; // to store longest palindrome


     // print all the palindrome words and also which is longest palindrome.

    for( std::list<std::string>::const_iterator it = listDict.begin(); it != listDict.end(); ++it )
    {

        if( palindromeTest( *it )  )
        {
            std::cout <<" the word -> " << *it << " is palindrome" << std::endl;
            // find max len of palindrome;
            maxLen = max( maxLen, it->size() );
            longestWord = *it ;// need to change code here ?? no idea how

        }

    }

    std::cout <<" the maximum len is = " << maxLen << std::endl;
    std::cout << " the word with maximum length is  " << longestWord ; // something is wrong here


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to point out how much memory you'd save for a longer dictionary by checking each word as you read it instead of storing them all into a huge container.

Comment: @chris, could you please elaborate what you mean by that. I am kind of new to C++. I havet explicity assigned any memory. Do i need to do for memory?

Comment: What I mean is this: Suppose your dictionary is 100k words. The way you're doing it now is to store them all into a list. If each element is 4 bytes for the pointer to the characters, that's 400K memory in the list (without the actual words). Now going through one at a time and using one string to hold the current one takes 4 bytes, but all you need to do is check whether it's a palindrome, check whether it's the longest so far, and move on. Now 400K might not matter, but eventually you might get into situations where you could save a very significant amount like this.

Comment: @chris, i got it what you mean. thanks for clarification. well iam on chap 5 of accelerated C++ and i thought to use containers to store values as shown in theory and to get used to in using container functions

Comment: Yes, they do work very well for holding things. It's just something to think about. It's one of the main differences in thinking about something. Either you can do step 1) for everything, then proceed to step 2) etc., or you can do all steps for each in sequence. Depending on the situation, one might work out a lot better, so it's always good to keep in mind that there's more than one way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors and lists both work equally well here, though a vector is more efficient.

You can find the longest word by changing

```
maxLen = max( maxLen, it->size() );
            longestWord = *it ;// need to change code here ?? no idea how
```

to

```
if (it->size() >= longestWord.size()) {longestWord = *it;}
```

(You don't actually need to keep track of maxlen since you can just call longestWord.size().)

Comment: Thanks Antimony ,  may please know why you think vector is good choice  over list?

Comment: Vectors take up less memory and have much better locality and cache usage. Unless you really need constant time random insertion and removal for large datasets, vectors beat lists.

Answer (score 1):

First the palindrome test. You are checking every character in the string twice which is unneeded. While in this particular case it will not matter, as it just doubles the time for that particular operation, for some similar operations it will change the semantics (consider `reverse` --conceptually very similar to the test for palindrome). To improve the check you can either use a loop counter from `0` to `input.size()/2` or use two pointers/iterators and run until they meet in the middle. Also note that iterating up to `input.size()/2` will leave a character that it never tested for strings with odd sizes, but that is fine.

When in need for a sequential container, you should always default to `std::vector<>`, rather than `std::list<>`. To manually find the maximum, you should change the call to `max` for a test that checks whether this element is larger than the previous max and then updates both the value of max and the location of the string (or the string itself). In this particular case, and if the number of repetitions is high, you could also consider not using a sequential container, but rather an associative one (`std::set<std::string>`) to avoid repetitions. But it is better not to store the words in memory altogether.

You should learn to use iterators, and the iterator's header in the standard library. For example, the reading loop can be converted to:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( readFile ),
           std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
           std::back_inserter( words );
```

The check for a palindrome can be a call to the `std::equal` algorithm:

```
bool isPalindrome( std::string const & str ) {
   return std::equal( str.begin(), str.begin()+str.size()/2,
                      str.rbegin() );
}
```

Finding the longest palindrome can also be done with an algorithm, by providing the appropriate functor:

std::vector::const_iterator max =
        std::max_element( words.begin(), words.end(),
                          []( std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs ) {
                              return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
                          });

(Using lambdas from C++11, in C++03 you would need to create a functor that performs the same comparison, which takes some more boilerplate code, but should not be much more complex)

As Antimony points out, if you only need this result, you don't need to keep all of the words in memory, in that case you could just test each word as is read and only store it if it is the longest palindrome up till now. This is not so easily implementable with standard algorithms, and it will be simpler to just roll your own loop.

While for learning purposes you probably want to follow the book (that targets C++03), a simple solution in C++11 could be:

```
std::string longestPalindrome( std::istream& stream ) {
   std::string longest;
   std::for_each( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
                  std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                  [&longest]( std::string const & word ) {
                      // if is longest palindrome so far
                      if (std::equal( word.begin(),
                                      word.begin()+word.size()/2,
                                      word.rbegin() 
                          && word.size() > longest.size())) 
                      {
                         longest = word;
                      }
                  });
   return longest;
}
int main() {
   std::ifstream readFile( "/Users/apple/palidndrome-ch5-10/dict.txt" );
   if ( !readFile ) {
      std::cerr << "failed to open file\n";      // [*]
      exit(1);
   }
   std::string longest = longestPalindrome( readFile );
   std::cout << "The longest palindrome is: '" << longest << "'\n";
}
```

[*]: Note, unless you really *need* it, it is better to just output "\n" than `std::endl`. The difference between the two is that `std::endl` will also *flush* the stream (force write), which will impact performance for no particular reason. As to when do you need to *flush*, basically when you need to ensure that the output is generated *now*, for example when querying a user:

```
std::cout << "Enter a number: " << std::flush; // Ensure that the user gets the message
                                               // before we lock waiting for an answer:
std::cin >> number;
```

And even in this case, it is clearer (if you need a newline) to dump "\n" and `std::flush` than `std::endl` (where it is not so clear that the flush is intentional, as there is way too much code that uses `std::endl` unendingly...

Comment: @samantha If you're using C++11 you could do `str.cbegin`, `cend`, and `crbegin` for the `std::equal` call in this case - for const correctness.

Comment: @Dave : Actually you would use ADL-found `begin()` and `end()` free-functions. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I've read that, but I can't get used to doing it. It doesn't read as well either (And who switches their underlying container type around anyway? And if they do, who switches to a non-std container? I don't think I have, even once) IMO it's improving a non-existent problem. Also, there aren't free cbegin/cend funcs right? That's a major problem.

Comment: @Dave : Any template that takes a container type as a template argument needs to worry about genericity. And the primary non-stdlib container that would be expected is a raw C-array (which `std::begin` and `std::end` behave well with, but member functions obviously don't).

Comment: @ildjarn Agreed. As long as the method isn't const... and then you've found a hole in the library and you're damned to writing your own cbegin/cend or something.

Comment: @Dave: `cbegin` and `cend` when calling `std::equal` do not improve const-correctness.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What if you're in a const method and acting on a member? But even in this situation I would argue it connotes usage more accurately - equal won't modify - but by using cbegin, whatever you pass it to *can't* modify

Comment: @Dave: Inside a function where `str` is `const`, the expression `str.begin()` will pick up the const overload and yield `const_iterator`s.